# How can I do this SQL query in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How can I do this query in PostgreSQL?

**My attempt in SQL**

```
SELECT stories.*
        where 
            user.id = 1 AND 
            user.id = usersources.userid AND 
            usersources.id = source.id AND 
            source.id = story.id 
            AND (story.id = user.id) IS NOT IN actions table
```

**Explanation in text**

```
SELECT
    stories
WHERE
 they have a relationship to a source AND
 sources has a story AND
 there IS NOT a row in actions from user and story (aka already acted on story)
```

**Context**

> This is an app that a user can subcribe to a number of news sources
>   and swipe on news. Once the user swipes on news they shouldn't be able
>   to see that news story again.

**Visual of tables**

[image: 1]

Comment: i smell homework

Comment: No :) This is actually for my iOS app. Trying to release it today but I have a hacky way and response times as 300ms :D Just trying to be clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think this will get you your criteria.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stories s
INNER JOIN actions a ON s.id = a.storyid
INNER JOIN sources s1 ON s.id = s1.id
INNER JOIN usersources us ON s1.id = us.sourceid
INNER JOIN users u ON us.userid = u.id
WHERE u.id = 1 
AND u.id != a.userid
```

Comment: I think you need to either `left join actions` or `not exists()`, because now you require that story already was acted by someone, just not by `u.id = 1`.

Comment: hmmm doesn't seem to be returning anything back :(